# The difference between (am+v.ing) and (will be+v.ing)

Tags: sentence-construction, future-tense, present-continuous, future-time

What is the difference grammatically and linguistically between:

> At this time next week, I will be visiting my uncle.
>
> At this time next week, I am visiting my uncle.

Answer (score 2):

From a listener's perspective, "At this time next week, I will be visiting my uncle' implies that you **intend** to visit him, but "At this time next week, I am visiting my uncle" carries a clear implication that you will, without fail and regardless of other circumstances, visit him. Use of this present tense in a future context is an expression of certainty.

Answer (score 1):

> At this time next week, I will be visiting my uncle.

This sentence uses [future continuous](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/future-continuous-future-perfect). We use it about a future event of unspecified duration.

> At this time next week, I am visiting my uncle.

This sentence uses [present continuous](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-continuous). We normally use it about something that we are in the middle of doing now. In this case, though, we are using it to describe a future plan.

To sum up: the meaning is approximately the same for both, but there is a small difference in emphasis: first is a **future event** and the second is a **future plan**.